# Testing angular directives with external templates in WebStorm fails but works outside of Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, webstorm, karma-runner

I'm trying to test angular directives that uses an external template with Jasmine running with Karma in WebStorm. I'm using OS X Mavericks and use WebStorm 7.0.2 and Karma version 0.10.2. I'm using the Karma runner in Webstorm that comes with Webstorm 7+.

I cloned https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing. If I run Karma from WebStorm I get the errors:

```
<pre>
/usr/local/bin/node /Applications/WebStorm.app/plugins/js-karma/js_reporter/karma-intellij/lib/intellijRunner.js --karmaPackageDir=/Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/node_modules/karma --serverPort=9876 --urlRoot=/
Testing started at 4:11 PM ...

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at http://localhost:9876/base/tpl/pane.html?1387211367000:1

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at http://localhost:9876/base/tpl/tabs.html?1387211367000:1

Process finished with exit code 0
</pre>
```

If I run karma from terminal or just open a terminal window from WebStorm it executes fine:

```
<pre>
karma start
WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9877/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0)]: Connected on socket X9kMCrZtNco2FEPaSEfb
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Mac OS X 10.9.0): Executed 9 of 9 SUCCESS (0.418 secs / 0.101 secs)
</pre>
```

Is there anything that needs to be changed in configuration karma configuration in WebStorm? I also have this issue if I try a similar set up but version v1.2.4 of angular.

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs for me if the karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor node module is missing

```
npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor -g
```

solves the problem - tests are successfully run in WebStorm

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem on my machine. I've added it before and I tried it again but I still get the same error.

Comment: I am having the same issue. installed it globally, and still getting the error in webstrom.